# Can I use tparm() without tputs or putp

Tags: c++, c, terminal, curses, terminfo

My understanding is that the function `char *tparm(char *str, ...);` just converts the given string `str` to an expanded parameterized version which will be fine to use with stdout outputting functions like `printf` or `cout`. But the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tparm) mentions -

> Parameterized strings should be passed through tparm to instantiate them. All terminfo strings [including the output of tparm] should be printed with tputs or putp.

So can I parse terminfo entries and use `tparm()` on them passing appropriate parameters and output them using stdout output functions? Also I'm doing the checks of non-tty output and ignoring these methods so I got that base covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you *can*.  But some capability strings include *padding* and *time delays*, which [`tparm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html#h3-Formatting-Output) assumes will be interpreted by [`tputs`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html#h3-Output-Functions).

For instance, the `flash` capability would use time-delays, which are passed along to `tputs` (using the syntax described in the [`terminfo(5)`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html#h3-Types-of-Capabilities) manual page).